# How can I receive a notification for Facebook page posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I co-manage several Facebook business pages which are updated daily.

I would like to keep abreast of what they post without having to check FB all the time - ideally through E-Mail.

I don't want to bother my colleagues about sending me dispatches every time they update the page - that would be time-consuming and silly.

Is there an automated way to keep me updated about new posts on a Facebook page?

Comment: Have you "Liked" the page(s) as well? I seem to get notifications from the pages I help manage and I don't recall doing anything more than clicking the "Like" button.

Comment: @AlE. THank you, I will check out all your suggestions and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've got email notifications set up in your page settings.

Go to you page, select ***Settings*** in the menu at the top, then ***Notifications*** on the menu to the left.

Make sure your Email setting is set to "on".

[image: Page notification settings]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you're only managing one Facebook page with your Facebook account, is to use IFTTT's [Facebook page](https://ifttt.com/facebook_pages) channel.

By using the "New status message on page" trigger, you can create a recipe that can alert you in just about any way you can think of. (Connect it to the Email channel, for instance, to get an email message. Or to the SMS channel, to get a text to your phone.)

Unfortunately, you can only define one Facebook page for the channel.